# Combine String Array and Iterator and sort

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I have 2 sets of values in my app - 1 from resources file and 1 from sharedpreferences. Is there an easy way to combine these both and create a Sorted List for the adapter? Here is my code:

```
  Spinner copyFromCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    Resources res = getResources();
    String [] predefinedCities = res.getStringArray(R.array.predefined_cities);

    // Necessary to add Iterator String to an adapter
    ArrayList<String> sortedPredefinedCities = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(predefinedCities))); 


    // Add values from our custom cities onto the Adapter via SharedPreferences

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Iterator<String> userCities = readCitiesFromPref(); // unsorted values

    while(userCities.hasNext()){

        adapter.add(userCities.next());
    }

/* TODO Way to sort both these values into alphabetical order */

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    copyFromCity.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adding readCitiesFromPref() method for clarifying why Iterator is being returned

```
protected Iterator<String> readCitiesFromPref() {

    // See if preferences store this
    JSONObject citiesList = null;
    Iterator<String> userCities = null;
    try {

        // Yes, so get the values out
        citiesList = new JSONObject(prefs.getAll());

        userCities = citiesList.keys();


    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {

        //TODO
    }

    return userCities;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is add those arrays/list to a `List`, sort and set it to adapter

```
    String [] predefinedCities = res.getStringArray(R.array.predefined_cities);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Iterator<String> userCities = readCitiesFromPref(); // unsorted values

    List<String> copyOfCities = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (userCities.hasNext()){

        copyOfCities.add(userCities.next());

    }

    ArrayList<String> sortedCities = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortedCities.addAll(copyOfCities);
    sortedCities.addAll(Arrays.asList(predefinedCities));
    Collections.sort(sortedCities);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            sortedCities);
```

Comment: but `userCities` is list object Right?

Comment: can you post `readCitiesFromPref();` method code... I dont understand why you need `Iterator`

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:
Convert the `string array` to a `List` 
convert the `Iterator` to `List` 
`Combine` them
`Sort`them like `Collections.sort(yourCombinedList);`
`feed` them to the adapter